# HOWTO: provide log-in (uid and pass) to Civicrm Contact - NEW or Existing

Tags: drupal, contacts

Is it possible to assign contacts created in Civicrm with Drupal UserID and Password during either CIVICRM contact creation or contact editing process with new, existing or imported contact?

I believe one can create "users" in Drupal and then export/sync the drupal user into CiviCRM contacts.  But, can it be done in reverse?

Help Appreciated

Thnks

Comment: Would this also work with Wordpress, and what about for Imported users?

Comment: which 'this' are you talking about? this would be better posted as a Comment, not an Answer. Also i tagged this discussion as Drupal since OP was specifying that. Aside from that, yes the Profile approach should also work in WP.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to go about this.

I wrote a somewhat convoluted guide a couple of years ago for creating a Drupal contact for a bunch of existing Civi contacts:
http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Creating+a+Drupal+user+for+every+CiviCRM+contact

However, I'd say the best practice today is to use the `civicrm_entity` Drupal module in combination with the `rules` module to automate this.  There's an excellent blog post about that here: https://civicrm.org/blogs/petednz/creating-drupal-users-made-easy-single-or-multiple-contacts-civi-imports-and-webforms

Answer (score 4):

If you have a contact already created and want to create a Drupal user manually (in a one-off or as-needed fashion), there is an action set up which can be used when you are viewing the contact record:

[image: Create user record]

Find it under **Actions > Create user record**.

Answer (score 1):

Creating CMS users during contact creation is simple, look at the advance settings on the profile. See my [article](https://aghstrategies.com/content/civicrm-profiles-beyond-contributions-registrations-part-1) on profiles.